# Как получить в script значение var

Tags: c#, htmlagilitypack, anglesharp

Есть скрипт с json, мне нужно его вытянуть, скрипт есть в html.

```
<script>
        var irep = new IREP.IREP({

            appUrlSecure : '/50/',
            appUrl: '/50/',
            apiUrl: 'https://retailedge.intel.com/api/',
            apiUrlSecure: 'https://retailedge.intel.com/api/',
            user: {"currentUID":"38108de32851484dbdf1a0d475b16789","cultureCode":"ru-RU","storeChainId":312895,"countryCode":"RU","features":{"trainingOnlyStores":false"},
            isRTL: false,
            isMotech: true,
            fileName: 'edgegames/stadium'
        }, irep);
        irep.execute();
    </script>
```

Нашел решение на `AngleSharp`, но не могу в string преобразовать.

```
var config = Configuration.Default.WithJs();
            //Create a new context for evaluating webpages with the given config
            var context = BrowsingContext.New(config);

            var document = await context.OpenAsync(req => req.Content(get.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result));
            var engine = context.GetService<JsScriptingService>();
            var jsValue = engine.EvaluateScript(document, "irep");
            var strings = jsValue.ToString();
```

Comment: Регуляркой можно вытянуть. В смысле содержимое `script` я бы получил с помощиью `HtmlAgilityPack`, а уже из JS вытащил бы json регуляркой. А сам json можно распарсить с помощиью `Newtonsoft.Json` или `System.Text.Json`, если .NET Core.

Comment: @aepot, В регулярках я почти 0, могли бы пример показать, пожалуйста

Comment: Расскажите конкретно, что вы хотите получить из этого json, и ссылку бы на страницу, где этот скрипт находится. Решение простое, на самом деле. И скажите, .NET Core или Framework?

Comment: Нужен только `currentUID`, вроде Framework, поэтому думаю подойдет `Newtonsoft.Json`

Comment: А ссылку на страницу можете дать, или она не публичная? Чтобы сразу проверить.

Comment: https://retailedge.intel.com/50/emea/edgegames/stadium только нужно зарегаться, либо я могу в вопрос html полный добавить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот, получился такой пример на базе консольного приложения

```csharp
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

```csharp
class Program
{
    private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { UseCookies = false });

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0");

        try
        {
            HtmlDocument doc = await GetIntelPageAsync("https://retailedge.intel.com/50/emea/edgegames/trainings");
            HtmlNodeCollection nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//script");
            Regex regex = new Regex(@"IREP\(({.*}), irep\)", RegexOptions.Singleline);
            foreach (HtmlNode node in nodes)
            {
                Match match = regex.Match(node.InnerHtml, 0);
                if (match.Groups.Count > 1)
                {
                    string json = match.Groups[1].Value;
                    dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
                    Console.WriteLine(data.user.currentUID);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static async Task<HtmlDocument> GetIntelPageAsync(string url)
    {
        using (HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url))
        {
            //request.Headers.Add("Cookie", "<вставить свои куки и раскомментировать>");
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
            {
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                using (Stream stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
                {
                    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
                    doc.Load(stream);
                    return doc;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Нужно вставить свои куки, которые были получены при авторизации. Я просто взял эту длинную строчку из заголовка запроса браузера и вставил в код. Можно еще попытаться добыть эти куки реализовав процесс аутентификации, но это уже другая интересная история.

Вывод в консоль

```
3c5896397fb240d8be432fb7ba10baa5
```

Если без кук, вывод в консоль такой

```
00000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: Да там я авторизирусь, все куки подтягиваются. Спасибо за решение